# If the equation $2x+2y+z=n$ has $28$ solutions, find the possible values of $n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. If the equation $2x+2y+z=n$ has $28$ solutions, find the possible values of $n$.

I tried taking $2x$ as $a$, and then $2y$ as $b$, and then finding the possibilities. However, I am not sure about the approach I've used.
A little hint would be appreciated.

$x$, $ y$ and $z$ belong to whole numbers.

Comment: do you mean $n$ or $n!$ ?

Comment: I believe there are some extra conditions on $x$, $y$ and $z$ also, such as they are positive integers etc.

Comment: Are they positive or whole?

Comment: My bad @AhmadBazzi. The exclamatory mark was out of sheer excitement!

Comment: @RushabhMehta, whole numbers

Comment: haha gotcha @AayushPaurana

Comment: @AayushPaurana First off, I'm not sure why there would be more than one $n$. Second, my approach seems to be generating results that show there are no possible values of *n*...

Comment: @AayushPaurana I got $n=17,18$ if the numbers are positive...

Comment: @RushabhMehta I'm eager to see you solution as well. Could you please post it?

Comment: When you say "whole numbers" what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $x,y,z$ are required to be positive integers.

Consider two cases . . .

**Case $(1)$:**$\;n$ is even.

From the equation $2x+2y+z=n$, it follows that $z$ is also even.

Writing $z=2w$, and $n=2m$, for some positive integers $w,m$, we get
\begin{align*}
&2x+2y+z=n\\[4pt]
\iff\;&2x+2y+2w=2m\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x+y+w=m\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
By the Stars-and-Bars formula, the equation 
$$x+y+w=m$$
has exactly ${\large{\binom{m-1}{2}}}$ positive integer solution triples $(x,y,w)$, for any given positive integer value of $m$, hence
\begin{align*}
&{\small{\binom{m-1}{2}}}=28\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&{\small{\frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{2}}}=28\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&m^2-3m+2=56\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&m^2-3m-54=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&(m-9)(m+6)=0\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&m=9\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&n=18\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

**Case $(2)$:**$\;n$ is odd.

From the equation $2x+2y+z=n$, it follows that $z$ is also odd.

Writing $z=2w-1$, and $n=2m-1$, for some positive integers $w,m$, we get
\begin{align*}
&2x+2y+z=n\\[4pt]
\iff\;&2x+2y+(2w-1)=2m-1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&x+y+w=m\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
As for case $(1)$, since $m$ is a positive integer such that the equation
$$
x+y+w=m
\qquad\qquad
$$
has exactly $28$ positive integer solution triples $(x,y,w)$, it follows that $m=9$, hence $n=2m-1=17$.

**Note:**$\;$If $x,y,z$ are only required to be *nonnegative* integers, then using arguments analogous to the ones given above, we get $n=12$ or $n=11$.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the equation $2x+2y+z=n$ has $28$ solutions when $x,y,z$ are positive integers.

Note that this is same as finding the powers of $t$ with coefficient $28$ in the following expansion.
$$(t^2+t^4+t^6+t^8+.......)^2(t+t^2+t^3+t^4+......)$$

$$\left(\dfrac{t^2}{1-t^2}\right)^2\times\dfrac{t}{1-t}=t^5\times\left(\dfrac{1}{1-t}\right)^3=t^5\times(1+t)^3\times\left(\dfrac{1}{1-t^2}\right)^3$$
$$=t^5(1+t)^3\left(\dbinom{2}{2}+\dbinom{3}{2}t^2+\dbinom{4}{2}t^4+\dbinom{5}{2}t^6+..........\right)$$

Note that the last part has the general term of $\dbinom{k}{2}t^{2k-4}$. Since $\dbinom{8}{2}=28$, the last part contains the term $28t^{12}$. So we have $28t^{17}+28t^{18}$

So, the value of $n$ can be either $17$ or $18$

Comment: You lost a square on $(t^2+t^4+t^6+t^8+\ldots)$  It is restored the next line